# A question about similarity transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Say $A$ is an $n\times n$ symmetric matrix such that every row (and hence column) has exactly $d<n$ non-zero entries.

- Does there exist similarity transformations on $A$ which will maintain these two properties? Does there exist an infinite number of such similarity transformations?
- Further suppose the matrix $A$ were such that $1$ was the only non-zero element allowed. Can the above question be answered now? (..surely now an infinite number of such similarity transformations can't exist..)

Comment: Your first question is not well posed. If $L$ os the identity matrix then $L^{-1}AL$ is similar to $A$. SO the answer to part 1 of your first bullet is yes. Next, take $c\ne0$ and $L=cI$ to get infinitely many similary transformations. It may be that you are concerned about cospectral regular graphs?

Comment: @ChrisGodsil Yes I am thinking of cospectral regular graphs! :D I guess I should have said that I want non-trivial similarity transformations!

Comment: You need to say what you mean by non-trivial. I expect you want to exclude permutation matrices too.

Comment: I want to disallow anything that would obviously lead to isomorphic graphs. I believe such an orbit does exist inside the group of transformations which would most often not lead to isomorphic graphs but would keep producing an infinite family of such graphs. I would think of it as 2 possible separate question (1) find a curve c(t) : [0,1] -> O(n) such that c(t)Ac(t)^{-1} is almost always some non-isomorphic d-regular adjacency matrix OR (2) find a B in O(n) such that B^kA(B^-1)^k is almost always some non-isomorphic d-regular adjacency matrix. I don't know which way of thinking is easier!